# Spring + Hibernate + Postgresql, Without XML, Error: The application must supply JDBC connections

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc, exception

I am trying to develop a fully annotation driven project using Spring Web MVC + Hibernate + Postgresql + Maven. But there is some problem with my DataSource configuration. I tried many combination but always getting this error:

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections**. All jars and connection string are good as it is working fine in XML version of project.

Code:

```
package com.matrix.nimble.config;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

/**
 * @author Narayanan Madaswamy
 */
public class NimbleInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{
        @Override
        public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)throws ServletException
        {
            AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext acwContext=new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
            acwContext.register(NimbleContextConfig.class);
            ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("SpringDispatcher",new DispatcherServlet(acwContext));
            dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
            dispatcher.addMapping("/init/*");
        }
}
```

Configuration Class:

```
package com.matrix.nimble.config;


import com.matrix.nimble.databeans.dao.user.UserDAO;
import com.matrix.nimble.databeans.dao.user.UserDAOImpl;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

/**
 *
 * @author Narayanan Madaswamy
 */
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.matrix.nimble.databeans.dao","com.matrix.nimble.controllers"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class NimbleContextConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter    {
    @Bean(name="viewResolver")
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver()
    {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean(name="dataSource")
    public DataSource getDataSource()
    {
        //BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        //dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        //dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/folksinventory");
        //dataSource.setUsername("postgres");
        //dataSource.setPassword("algorithm");
        SimpleDriverDataSource dataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource(new org.postgresql.Driver(), "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/folksinventory", "postgres", "password");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name="sessionFactory")
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource)
    {
        LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);
        sessionBuilder.scanPackages("com.matrix.nimble.databeans");
        sessionBuilder.setProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        return sessionBuilder.buildSessionFactory();
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name="transactionManager")
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.current_session_context_class","thread");
        properties.put("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache","true");
        properties.put("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache","true");
        properties.put("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class","org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory");
        return properties;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry resourceRegistry)
    {
        resourceRegistry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
}
```

UserDAO:

```
package com.matrix.nimble.databeans.dao.user;

import com.matrix.nimble.databeans.user.User;

/**
 *
 * @author Narayanan Madaswamy
 */
public interface UserDAO {
    public User validateUser(String loginid,String loginpass);
    public String getErrmsg();
    public boolean isSuccess();
}
```

UserDAOImpl:

```
package com.matrix.nimble.databeans.dao.user;

import com.matrix.nimble.databeans.user.User;
import com.matrix.nimble.utils.MadCryptor;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

/**
 *
 * @author Narayanan Madaswamy
 */
@Service
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private String errmsg;
    private boolean success;

    public UserDAOImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public User validateUser(String loginid, String loginpass) {
        User user = null;
        Session session = null;
        setSuccess(false);
        setErrmsg(null);
        try {
            MadCryptor mc = new MadCryptor();
            loginid = mc.createHashedUsername(loginid);
            session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
            String hql = "from User where username=:logId";
            Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
            query.setString("logId", loginid);
            user = (User) query.uniqueResult();
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(user.getActivesince());
            if (!mc.validatePassword(loginpass, (cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) / 2) + ":" + user.getPair() + ":" + user.getPassword())) {
                user = null;
                setErrmsg("Invalid username or password");
            } else if (user.getIsallowed() == 0) {
                user = null;
                setErrmsg("Your account is disabled. Contact administrator");
            }
            else
            {
                setSuccess(true);
            }
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException exce) {
            user = null;
            setErrmsg("Something bad happend. Please contact administrator.");
        } finally {
            if (session != null) {
                session.close();
            }
        }
        return user;
    }

    public String getErrmsg() {
        return errmsg;
    }

    public void setErrmsg(String errmsg) {
        this.errmsg = errmsg;
    }

    public boolean isSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess(boolean success) {
        this.success = success;
    }
}
```

Login Controller:

```
package com.matrix.nimble.controllers.commons;

/**
 *
 * @author Narayanan Madaswamy
 */
import com.matrix.nimble.databeans.dao.user.UserDAO;
import com.matrix.nimble.databeans.dao.user.UserDAOImpl;
import com.matrix.nimble.databeans.user.User;
import com.matrix.nimble.models.commons.Login;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/login/")
@SessionAttributes(value = "fsimSession", types = NimbleSession.class)
public class LoginController {
    @Autowired
    UserDAO userDAO;
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String loginPage(ModelMap model)
    {
        model.addAttribute("login", new Login());
                model.addAttribute("errMsg", null);
                return "login";
    }
        @RequestMapping(value="authenticate",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String authenticateUser(@ModelAttribute Login login, ModelMap model)
    {
                //UserDAO userDAO = ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean(UserDAOImpl.class);
                User user = userDAO.validateUser(login.getUsername(),login.getPassword());
                if(!userDAO.isSuccess())
                {
                    model.addAttribute("errMsg", "<span class='text-red'>"+userDAO.getErrmsg()+"</span>");
                    return "login";
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Reached Here");
                    NimbleSession fsess=new NimbleSession(user.getId(),user.getFullname(),user.getGroupname(),user.getGroupid());
                    model.addAttribute("fsimSession", fsess);
                    return "redirect:../home/";
                }
    }
}
```

Project Structure:

[image]

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.matrix</groupId>
    <artifactId>nimble</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-Beta</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>nimble</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Nimble Module Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.matrix</groupId>
            <artifactId>utils</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-Beta</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Nimble Module Dependencies Ends -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
            <version>3.0-b72</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logmanager</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logmanager</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml</groupId>
            <artifactId>classmate</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.b2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-jta_1.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.20.0-GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jandex</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Bootstrap Webjars Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
            <artifactId>adminlte</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
            <artifactId>font-awesome</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
            <artifactId>ionicons</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
            <artifactId>angular</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Error Details:

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

Type Exception Report

Message Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections

Root Cause

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.java:44)
    org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:386)
    org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:84)
    org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:109)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:47)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:146)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:172)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:148)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1927)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1896)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1874)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:919)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2610)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2593)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2422)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2417)
    org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:501)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:371)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1339)
    org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:87)
    org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.uniqueResult(AbstractQueryImpl.java:964)
    com.matrix.nimble.databeans.dao.user.UserDAOImpl.validateUser(UserDAOImpl.java:48)
    com.matrix.nimble.controllers.commons.LoginController.authenticateUser(LoginController.java:41)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:180)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:440)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:428)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

Tomcat Version : **8.0**,
Spring Release : **4.3.1**,
Hibernate Version: **5.0.1**,
PostgreSQL Version: **10**,
PGSQL Jar Version: **9.1**

Comment: Error raised at line number 48 of UserDAOImpl, which is : **user = (User) query.uniqueResult();**

Comment: See this in the stack trace `UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl`? This class is chosen in Hibernate as the connection provider when no DataSource is found and none of the properties specify alternative means of connecting to a database. I've never used CDI, but I'm fairly certain this means your `getSessionFactory` is called with a `null` for a DataSource.